# Is there a term for properties that capture a true/false/null status?

Tags: boolean, terminology

I'm doing a bunch of refactoring to change properties that were previously merely boolean (true/false) to a state that can also capture the null status  (true/false/null).  I find myself forced to describe the new status as "true/false/null".  This is both lengthy and not particularly meaningful to non-dev folks in the business that don't use the term 'boolean' or 'null'.

Is there a term that better describes the new property type that I'm introducing?

Comment: truthy and falsy

Comment: [Truth-value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_value)? For example, there exist terms "truth-value gaps" and "truth-value gluts".

Answer (score 0):

This is basically known as three-valued logic (3VL), a term which allows the value to be `true`, `false` or some indeterminate value.

Wikipedia has a [page on 3VL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) which you may find of interest.

I've heard some people use the term tri-state logic for this as well but I suspect that will cause a lot of electronics enthusiasts to get all hot and bothered about misappropriation of the term - it means something quite different in that arena (putting a device in high impedance mode to minimise its effect on the circuit as a whole).